# Error while Autowiring Tracer in Service Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have autowired ***org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer*** in a service but getting the following error while building the project (mvn clean install). Although The applications runs through IDE and code works perfectly, but I need a way to remove the error while compiling the project.

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 3 of constructor in
> com.mmt.corporate.payments.PaymentService required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer' in your configuration.

have included org.springframework.cloud.sleuth this way in pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to inject `Tracer` through parameterized constructor of `PaymentService`. You may not be  _autowiring_ it. Can you please add your implementation of `PaymentService`?

Comment: I've tried both. Yes this error stack is of constructor autowiring.

Answer (score 2):

The Sleuth's `Tracer` was present in version 1.3.x. Starting from version 2.x there's no more `Tracer` from Sleuth. There's one from Brave. Can you please upgrade to the latest version?